# How to deploy firebase website from Gitlab CD?

Tags: firebase, gitlab, devops, continuous-deployment

I am maintaining my code in gitlab. I have hosted my website in firebase.  I want to implement continuous deployment to firebase from gitlab.

**Here is my current YML script**

```
image: node:alpine


deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
    - npm build
    - firebase deploy --non-interactive --token "1//0gUT4kVkAzDa9CgYIARAAGBASNwF-L9IrGNXptJQ0YybVEjtYCttSystVDdE35i-IzSm3MwcnxDyfwT2FdQPCvdUa4o5GOVVUyrA"
```

**I am getting the following error from the Gitlab job**

```
Error: Authorization failed. This account is missing the following required permissions on project <project-id>:

  firebase.projects.get
  firebasehosting.sites.update
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

Copy the below code and paste it in your .yml file:

```
image: node:alpine

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
    - firebase deploy --non-interactive --token "<token>" --project <project ID>
```

For the complete tutorial, you could visit this [link](https://salmansulthan.wordpress.com/2019/10/23/firebase-hosting-deployment-automation-with-gitlab-ci/).